# JS Fullcalendar repeat events in month view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using this js fullcalendar plugin and it is great. 
What I'm trying to do is to set a event for each weekday but when I use `rendering: 'background'` the events are not showing.
If I remove rendering option and events appear in the calendar.

```
events: [{
    title:"My repeating event",
    start: '00:00',
    end: '23:59', 
    dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
}],
```

This is how I'm adding events. But I really need to show them as background events. Also tried to make it full day event but no success.

If anyone can help me I will really appreciate it.

Comment: background events will only appear as a coloured background, there's no info about the event displayed, it simply colours in the time period covered by the event. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/ . Do you see that colouring at least when you set `rendering:"background"`?

Comment: I see coloring only when remove dow parameter but without dow parameter the event is only for one day.

Comment: it works for me whether dow is there or not. Bear in mind the colouring is only on the week or day views, not on the month view. And without dow it still repeats for me too

Comment: Actually that is my question is it possible to add recurring event with `rendering: 'background'`

Comment: yes. it's identical to a regular event except that you add `rendering: "background"` to the event properties. No other change should be necessary

Comment: Apparently there is something because this is my event and is not visible in month view
`"events":[
{
 "id":"tIhzu5Ni",
 "title":"Repeating event",
 "allDay":true,
 "start":"2016-10-05",
 "end":"2016-10-06",
 "rendering":"background",
 "dow":[0,6],
 "editable":false,
 "color":"#009e0f"
 }
]`

Comment: remove the start and end dates. You can't define both recurrence and specific start/end dates (especially so when those dates don't cover the dates allow by the dow setting).

Comment: Thanks a lot this was the problem. You can post an answer so I can rate it.

Comment: will do. P.S. your original posted code sample did not have this issue (since it uses times not dates, which is allowed), hence I didn't spot the problem sooner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, your issue is that you are specifying both days of the week (using the `dow` parameter) and `start`/`end` dates in your event. FullCalendar doesn't allow to you include the dates if you want an event to appear as a recurring background event.

Therefore, as per the example in the comments, you should change from:

```
"events":[ { 
  "id":"tIhzu5Ni", 
  "title":"Repeating event", 
  "allDay":true, 
  "start":"2016-10-05", 
  "end":"2016-10-06", 
  "rendering":"background", 
  "dow":[0,6], 
  "editable":false, 
  "color":"#009e0f" 
} ]
```

to:

```
"events":[ { 
  "id":"tIhzu5Ni", 
  "title":"Repeating event", 
  "allDay":true, 
  "rendering":"background", 
  "dow":[0,6], 
  "editable":false, 
  "color":"#009e0f" 
} ]
```

Note that it's perfectly legal to use start/end *times* (Durations), but not dates, in this scenario (assuming the event is not an all-day event). See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/ for more detail.